# Is there an easy way to get the mapping of a categorical column from a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, r, pandas, spss, categorical-data

For a project, I was given data in SPSS .sav-files that had previously been handled using R. I'm now trying to "translate" into Python and have been using pandas for that, more specifically the very handy `read_spss(...)`-function.

The original data represents a graph where each row contains info about a node and some columns contain info about each node's outgoing edges. There is an additional identifier associated with each row/node that for some reason is not explicitly given as a column. However, when preserving categorical columns using `read_spss(convert_categoricals=True)`, I can see these identifiers in the data frame's foreign key columns.

My problem is that there seem to be three different ways to represent the data in these categorical columns:

1. Using `read_spss(convert_categoricals=True)`, I get the category names for each row.
2. Using `df["categorical_column"].cat.codes`, I get the category code for each row.
3. Using `read_spss(convert_categoricals=False)`, I get IDs for each row which are completely different from the codes obtained using the second option.

What I want to have is a map from the IDs obtained using the third option (because these are used as foreign keys to other rows in the data frame) to the category names obtained using the first option. However, I can only think of ways to this that seem rather inconvenient and expensive (i. e. importing the data frame twice, creating a new data frame that combines row IDs and row categories, and then creating a python dictionary from that, repeating the process for each foreign key-column).

Is there an easier way to do this?

**Edit**: After some3128's answer, I settled on this (which is basically my original idea, but reading only the relevant columns):

```
categorical_df = pd.read_spss(self.path_to_network_data, usecols=columns_to_read)
non_categorical_df = pd.read_spss(self.path_to_network_data, usecols=columns_to_read, convert_categoricals=False)

# Merge along PK column (suffix "_x": categorical, "_y": non-categorical)
merged_df = pd.merge(categorical_df, non_categorical_df, on="PK")

# Extract a dictionary Unique_SoSciNu -> Info String from this data
info_dict = {}
for n in relation_columns:
    nx, ny = f"{n}_x", f"{n}_y"
    info_dict.update({int(row[ny]): row[nx] for i, row in merged_df.iterrows() if not pd.isna(row[ny])})
```

The last stop takes quite long, but the result I get should be correct.

Comment: `read_spss` has a `usecols=` parameter. That might help make loading the dataframe less expensive, by limiting it to the columns of interest (or at least ignoring columns you know aren't needed). Perhaps an alternative is to make a new CSV which is a merged version of CSV1 and CSV2 - then you only need to load that larger CSV once? Whether that's helpful or not depends on how often the tables change. When you say "repeating the process for each ... column" - I think you could do it in one go after you load both CSVs, i.e. you don't need to repeatedly load per column. Unless I've misunderstood.